# Drop Chargebacks in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that keeps accounting values.

Within the various groups, negative values, i.e. chargebacks, can occur that I want to drop from the dataframe along with their positive counterpart.

Example:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5], 
                "Date": [44958,44958,44959,44959,44959,44959,44988,44988],
                "Amount": [39.99,24.15,15.5,-15.5,15.5,8.99,12.99,-12.99], 
                "Type" : ["Sale","Sale","Sale","Sale","Sale","Sale","Sale","Sale"],
                "Product": ["Pencil","Pencil","Book","Book","Book","Ruler","Pen","Pen"],
                "Tax": [2.7993,1.6905,1.085,-1.085,1.085,0.6293,0.9093,-0.9093],
                "Fee": [0.03999,0.02415,0.0155,-0.0155,0.0155,0.00899,0.01299,-0.01299]})
```

The above example should ultimately look like this:

```
    ID  Date    Amount  Type    Product Tax     Fee
0   1   44958   39.99   Sale    Pencil  2.7993  0.03999
1   2   44958   24.15   Sale    Pencil  1.6905  0.02415
2   3   44959   15.50   Sale    Book    1.0850  0.01550
3   4   44959   8.99    Sale    Ruler   0.6293  0.00899
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Where did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to sum up the items and only keep those with positive `Amount`:

```py
df = df.groupby(["ID", "Date", "Type", "Product"], as_index=False).sum()
df = df[~np.isclose(df["Amount"], 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One difficulty may arise if you have several chargebacks for the same ID.

This should be fairly immune to that: sort by `Amount`, group by `ID` and cumulative sum. When that cumulative sum becomes positive, those entries need to be kept.

```py
keep = df.sort_values('Amount').groupby('ID')['Amount'].transform('cumsum') > 0
newdf = df.loc[keep]

>>> newdf
   ID   Date  Amount  Type Product     Tax      Fee
0   1  44958   39.99  Sale  Pencil  2.7993  0.03999
1   2  44958   24.15  Sale  Pencil  1.6905  0.02415
4   3  44959   15.50  Sale    Book  1.0850  0.01550
5   4  44959    8.99  Sale   Ruler  0.6293  0.00899
```